# Getting can't find '__main__' module when trying to run arbitrary python script on docker container run

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a requirement where customers would upload some script which is supposed to do calculations, and it should be computed and then I get back that value. I decided to use a setup where a FastAPI app exposes an upload API, which then hits a docker container run, with the uploaded script.

requirements.txt

```
fastapi[all]
uvicorn[standard]
python-jose
pydantic[email]
docker
python-multipart
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Use a base image with Python pre-installed
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the application code into the container
COPY . .

# Set the default command to run the application
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

app.py <-- This contains the FastAPI app which has the upload route and tries to run docker container with the script

```
import docker
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File

app = FastAPI()
client = docker.from_env()

@app.post('/execute-script')
async def execute_script(script: UploadFile = File(...)):
    # Save the script to a temporary file
    script_path = '/tmp/script.py'
    with open(script_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(await script.read())

    # Define container resource limits
    cpu_limit = '0.5'
    mem_limit = '20m'

    # Create a new container to run the script with resource constraints
    container = client.containers.run(
        'python:3.8.17-slim',
        f'timeout 3s python {script_path}',
        remove=True,
        cpu_period=100000,
        cpu_quota=int(float(cpu_limit) * 100000),
        mem_limit=mem_limit,
        memswap_limit=mem_limit,
        volumes={'/tmp/script.py': {'bind': '/tmp/script.py', 'mode': 'rw'}}
    )

    # Get the container logs
    logs = container.logs().decode('utf-8')

    return {'output': logs}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

To build the image:

> docker build -t my-python-app .

To run the image:

> docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 8000:8000 my-python-app

Now, everything so far is fine. However, when I try to upload a valid python script file, it gives Internal server error saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 435, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 284, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 241, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 167, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/app/app.py", line 19, in execute_script
    container = client.containers.run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 887, in run
    raise ContainerError(
docker.errors.ContainerError: Command 'timeout 3s python /tmp/script.py' in image 'python:3.8.17-slim' returned non-zero exit status 1: b"/usr/local/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/tmp/script.py'\n"
```

The script file I used is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("I am python!")
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I realized the problem was due to assumption that

```
volumes={'/tmp/script.py': {'bind': '/tmp/script.py', 'mode': 'rw'}}
```

would mount the fast api container's /tmp/script.py to the new container which was about to be run using container.run(...).

However, it doesn't work like that. The host machine's /tmp/script.py is what would be mounted.

To make the above work, we have to run the fast api docker image like so:

> docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp/:/tmp -p 8000:8000 my-python-app

Now things are working as expected. Also, one minor correction,

```
    # Get the container logs
    logs = container.decode('utf-8')
```

instead of

```
    # Get the container logs
    logs = container.logs().decode('utf-8')
```

AND

```
        volumes={'/tmp': {'bind': '/tmp', 'mode': 'rw'}}
```

instead of

```
        volumes={'/tmp/script.py': {'bind': '/tmp/script.py', 'mode': 'rw'}}
```